# Writing a shell script to output database data

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a bash script that allows me to perform this SQL query:

Lets say that it's:

```
SELECT * FROM CUST OUTFILE '/g/c/data/reports/cust_info/q.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

How would I be able to execute this command in bash, so that I could output the csv file?

Answer (score 1):

If your database is a postgres, use `-c` option. If it's mysql, aim for `--execute`. In any other case, read the manual.

And you can always use:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM blah etc..." | yoursqlclient
```